# Stop the while function on time

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

I need to create a string up to the point when I get a * character and I would like to do it without having to double the condition `(c!='*')`. I tried `while(){...}` and `do {...} while()` but the * is still added.

Here is a piece of code:

```
while (c!='*')
            {
                c=dec.checkChar(dec.extractCode(t, d));
                d=d.shiftRight(7);
                if (c!='*')decoded+=c;
            }
```

Comment: what is the language you use?

Comment: @MyDog It's Java. Sorry, added a tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(true){
            c=dec.checkChar(dec.extractCode(t, d));
            if(c=='*'){
                 break;
              }
            d=d.shiftRight(7);
            decoded+=c;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change `c` immediately after checking it in the outer loop.  Instead, restructure you logic to process the `c` you just checked wasn't an exit condition, and the make updating the `c` the last thing you do.